# Parameters pass by value vs parameters as local variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, logic

Say for example you have a function like below

```
var value = 1;
function test(myVar) {
  myVar = 2
}
test(value)
console.log(value)
//prints out 1
```

Now, I have read that there are two things that happen in JS functions.

1) Javascript passes primitives by value. When "value" is passed as an argument to test(), a copy is created that is separate from the global variable "value". Therefore the "myVar" is a separate variable from "value"

2) Parameters in JS functions are really just local variables to the function. So, the "myVar" parameter has scope only inside of the test() function.

I know both statements are true, but which one of these statements causes console.log(value) to print out 1

Comment: *Both* statements are true; they're not really contradictory in any way.

Comment: They are both correct, and both explain why `1` is logged.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those statements are true. The reason why it prints out 1 is that, as you mentioned, parameters are passed by value. As such, the value of your variable `value` is never altered.

Although point #2 is also true, it doesn't really have much to do with this behaviour. it is more related to doing something like using myVar outside of that function's scope.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the statements are correct

Please check this URL from Mozilla [Variable Scope in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_Types#Variable_scope)